# HQL returns null when SQL equivalent does not

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, oracle-sqldeveloper

so i have a HQL code in Java that does

```
ClassA myAObj = null;
myAObj = (ClassA) hs.get(ClassA.class, classId)
```

this line executes without issue many times. however, there are cases for a few primary key ID where HQL return a null value and myAObj is null. This is considered odd because i took the console's SQL equivalent scriptand ran it in SQL developer and i did not get a null result.

What is the possible cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `classId` you are passing to `hs.get(ClassA.class, classId)` is not present(not matching) in your table records.

Better you debug code or print `classId` value then verify that record exist in your table.

Comment: that's exactly what i did and i got the classId, and ran it in my DB and the record does indeed exist. just wondering where it means i have to clean my Tomcat server, or something..

Comment: @bouncingHippo verify by disabling your hibernate catch.